# Why does "Home" button call `onDestroy()` in my Android app?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

On the [Android dev page](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/state-changes#covered), it says pressing the "Home" or "Overview" button does not invoke `onDestroy`,

but in my app, it keeps calling `onDestroy`. Are there any clues?

(detail situation below)

I've built a simple app that switches from the main activity to a second activity,

but if I press the "Home" or "Overview" button on the second activity, the `onDestroy` gets called.

So when I go back to my app again, it shows the main activity, not the second activity.

Is this normal?

Should I save the state if I want to go back to the *last* activity (not the main activity) after pressing the Home or the Overview button and coming back to my app?

[Android dev page](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/state-changes#covered) that I read:

> If a new activity or dialog appears in the foreground, taking focus and completely covering the activity in progress, the covered activity loses focus and enters the Stopped state. The system then, in rapid succession, calls onPause() and onStop().

and

> Note: When the user taps the Overview or Home button, the system behaves as if the current activity has been completely covered.

So it is supposed to invoke only `onPause` and `onStop`, **not** `onDestroy`, isn't it?

Comment: in developer options on the device, have you enabled aggressive activity background destroying option

Comment: @ConradB I checked, but I haven't. Thanks for the comment! This question was asked like a few hours ago, but no one answered, so I myself posted the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found the culprit!

the problem was that I set `android:noHistory="true"` on the second activity, in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Making this option `true` let the activity not leave the history,
so if another activity comes to the foreground and the user pushes the back button, the previous activity(noHistory=true) does **not** show up.

Similarly, if the user pushes the Home or the Overview button, then the user tries to come back to our app, the last activity(noHistory=true) does **not** show up either.

Comment: Excellent, I'm just a tester, so my suggestion was from my limited experience only ; just to get you to persevere and hope to understand your solution. Thanks for posting answer.

Comment: Thanks for the question and answer. You saved my day

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the Code in your Question or we can't help you.

Maybe you are calling `finish()` in MainActivity after you call `startActivity(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class)` ?

Use the edit-function and show us your code then we can help you more.

Comment: Oh, there was no answer for 6 hours so I was writing my own answer while you were typing this :) thank you so much! I tried to search if I called finish, but it wasn't called. I finally found the problem, it was the AndroidManifest file!

Comment: @starriet i didn't know that android:noHistory="true" does something like this. i thought i could help you, but now YOU teached ME. :D